# typescript poker filter pairs from 7 card deck

Tags: typescript, playing-cards

I am making a poker game and poker-evaluator that I am using to tell me only the outcome from the cards

```
'invalid hand',
    'high card',
    'one pair',
    'two pairs',
    'three of a kind',
    'straight',
    'flush',
    'full house',
    'four of a kind',
    'straight flush'
```

I am trying to know which cards in the sets are responsible for the "win".

I made a filter for duplicates and full house (i.e. three duplicates of same number and 2 duplicates of other number).

How can I improve the quality of the code below?

```
     interface CardDuplicate{
       Id:Array<number>
      } 
      const getDuplicates =(Firsts:Array<string>,FullArray:Array<string>)=> {
          let duplicates ={} as CardDuplicate;
          for (let i = 0; i < Firsts.length; i++) {
       
        const key = Firsts[i] as keyof  CardDuplicate
          if(key in duplicates) {
         
              duplicates[key].push(i);
          }else if (Firsts.lastIndexOf(key) !== i) {
              duplicates[key] = [i];
          }
        }
          
         let Type = "none";
         if(duplicates === undefined){
    
          return {Type:Type,Cards:[]};
         }
           const Obj = Object.keys(duplicates).map((key)=> {
        key = key as keyof CardDuplicate
        if(duplicates !== undefined && duplicates[key] !== undefined){
  if(duplicates[key ].length > 2 && Object.keys(duplicates).length > 1){
    Type= "Full house";
  }else if( Object.keys(duplicates!).length > 2){
    Type= "three pairs";
  }else if(duplicates[key].length == 2 && Object.keys(duplicates).length > 1){
    Type= "two pairs";
  }else if(duplicates[key].length == 2 && Object.keys(duplicates).length == 1){
    Type= "one pairs";
  }
   return duplicates[key ].map((data:string)=>{return FullArray[data]});
}else{
  return []
}
          });
        
          return {Type:Type,Cards:Obj};
        
      };
    function CheckIfPairs(Item:Array<string>){
    
      const Firsts:Array<string>=[];
      const Letters:Array<string>=[];
     
     Item.map((data:string)=>{
      const Number:string = data.split('')[0]
       Firsts.push(Number);
       Letters.push(data.split('')[1])
     })
    return getDuplicates(Firsts,Item)
    }
    
  

    //s = spades h = hearts c = clubs (♣), d= diamonds
         console.log(CheckIfPairs([
              "2s",
              "2d",
              "6c",
              "3s",
              "8d",
              "4h", 
              "9c",
            ]))
```

Comment: Please start by [autoformatting](https://prettier.io/playground) your code (but only before someone writes an answer) (hint: select the `--parser typescript` option).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, please format the code, so it's easier to read.

Look at your `duplicates === undefined`. These seem overly-cautious checks. How can these occur?

It also seems like `Object.keys(duplicates).length` is assumed to be the number of duplicates. But it seems like it is a reverse index of cards, and there may just be a single card in the entries, so some of the logic may be off.

Hope this helps.